# After upgrading to MySQL 8. Total large memory allocated = 0

Tags: mysql

So maybe I missed something but I haven't found an answer yet.. I upgraded from MySQL 5.7 to 8 and using the same my.cnf file.  When I run "show engine innodb status\G", it shows **Total large memory allocated = 0**.

In MySQL 5.7, **Total large memory allocated = 87912611840**

Can someone clear this up for me?  TIA

**Details...**

```
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 0
Dictionary memory allocated 375221
Buffer pool size   5242410
Free buffers       5229168
Database pages     13236
Old database pages 5040
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 13094, created 142, written 158
778.00 reads/s, 0.06 creates/s, 10.18 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 571 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 13236, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
```

**my.cnf**

```
[mysqld]
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql

performance_schema=ON

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
#tmpdir=/var/lib/tmp

skip-name-resolve
key_buffer_size = 20M
max_allowed_packet = 64M
tmp_table_size = 512M
max_heap_table_size = 512M
join_buffer_size = 1M
ft_min_word_len = 3
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 32M


# InnoDB Settings
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 80G
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_log_file_size = 256M # default: 48M


# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
sql_mode = ''

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log

[mysqld_safe]
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
open-files-limit=98304
```

```
mysql> show variables like 'innodb_buffer%';
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name                       | Value          |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size       | 134217728      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct         | 25             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename         | ib_buffer_pool |
| innodb_buffer_pool_in_core_file     | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances        | 8              |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort       | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size             | 85899345920    |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: 0 means unlimited as your old number is very very high

Comment: Hmm.  I also did a quick test by setting innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G and it's still showing 0.

Comment: mysql doesn't rewrite your file, it only reads the configuration., so add anew comment to the ifle and see if it is there

Comment: Sorry.. I don't understand what you're saying.  I know the cnf file isn't overwritten... what comment are you referring to?  innodb_buffer_pool_size is a dynamic variable and doesn't need a restart.

Comment: when you added th 8G you said that it returned to 0, so my suggestion is to add any comment line to the ini file and check after saving if it is still there after opening again

Comment: Yes.. any edits to the cnf file is there.  BTW.. this is on CentOS 7.